# Não consigo mudar o collate da minha coluna no mysql para utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, formatação, utf-8

Bom dia Pessoal.

Estou com um problema em relação a alteração do collate de uma coluna no meu banco de dados. Um exemplo de como estou rodando:

```
ALTER TABLE `minhaTabela` CHANGE COLUMN `nome` `nome` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' AFTER `id`;
```

Sempre que executo, não altera e deixa o campo nulo. Ele só me permite deixar com o formato utf8_unicode. Isso está me deixando nervoso um pouco e não encontro uma solução. A tabela é MyISAM, não está como InnoDB.. não sei se isso tem relação.

Alguma ideia de como me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Este exemplo funcionou comigo:

```
ALTER TABLE `minhaTabela` CHANGE `nome` `nome` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

NOTA: não há diferença na query para alterar o COLLATE entre o motor MyISAM e InnoDb

Comment: Eu resolvi. Percebi que teria de mudar os campos todos para o padrão do banco e converter todos. Executei o código e funcionou. Mas só funcionou devido a conversão.